# Variable not recognised in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, blackjack

This code evaluates a blackjack hand. It works in all cases except when the function is called within the function, when an "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'feedback' referenced before assignment" message appears.

The thing I don't understand is that the code gets all the way to the bottom line where it prints the answer, and I would have presumed was finished, before throwing an error.

Here is the code

```
def evaluate_hand(hand):
    score = sum(hand)
    if score > 21 and 11 not in hand:
        feedback = 0
    elif score > 21 and 11 in hand:
        hand.remove(11)
        hand.append(1)
        evaluate_hand(hand) # problem seems to be here (?)
    elif len(hand) >= 5:
        feedback = 22
    elif score == 21 and 11 in hand:
        feedback = 23
    else:
        feedback = score
    print('Score for evaluation purposes = {}'.format(feedback))

# example inputs:

evaluate_hand([1,8,10])     #normal hand
evaluate_hand([10,5,10])    # bust hand
evaluate_hand([3,1,5,5,2])   # five card trick
evaluate_hand([5,8,11])     # 'bust' hand including an ace
```

Comment: the problem isnt there, its that entire `elif` section, you don't return anything in the function (or that line you've commented` so it just continues to the end of the function where you havent used `feedback` through that code flow. Returning that `evaluate_hand` call may fix this issue

Comment: `evaluate_hand(hand)` should be `feedback = evaluate_hand(hand)` or `return evaluate_hand(hand)`. And function should *return* `feedback` at the end.

Comment: @trincot - setting `feedback` to the function calls result would add at least one erroneous print output to the end of the output

Comment: It would not be an erroneous print, just a duplicate print. If that is just debugging code, it doesn't matter IMHO. But function must return `feedback` of course for this to work.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the feedback, guys. It's working following your tweaks and I'm trying to wrap my head around exactly why.